# Multiple partitions for "different storages"

Tags: android

We are making an app that will be basically the home for some Android devices.

Based on that, the idea is to have different partitions, for example, one for videos, one for apps and one for photos. What we want to achieve here is to prevent someone uses the entire storage capacity in recording a video, so with these partitions you can make videos until the videos partition gets full, and if this get full you still can install apps and take pictures.

So, here is the question. Is this doable? I know we have the option to make this via "logic", using folders and maintaining the used space count and make some validations. But the partitions approach seems to be more "clean and clear".

Can we make multiple partitions (external or internal storage)?

Can we save files to specific partitions? (I know that Android 4.4 provide some way of doing something similar but we are using Android 4.0/4.1)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. Don't go formatting your users storage and create new partitions. This will cause an extreme amount of problems and unexpected behavior, especially for your users. Also a word of advice: all the functionality you are putting effort into is already in android by default, users probably aren't waiting for yet another launcher/recording/file organizer app.

Comment: @dtech this is not another organizer app, is a specific tablet for a specific audience that need some restrictions. That's the origin of my question. So, for example, if I have to limit the storage capacity for videos, how do I do it?

Comment: Build your own Android distribution and flash it on the rom, similarly to what HTC, Samsung and [amateurs](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) do. The only way an app could do this is if the phone is rooted, and even then its tricky. This is a very non-trivial amount of effort.